# Jquery how to check own child element only

Tags: jquery, checkbox, each

I want to implement jquery `each function` in here. Menu contains submenu, if submenu has not been checked when it's parent menu is being checked, then it have to be stopped to submit. But here `sports` and `vehicle` menu consider each other `submenu` as common `submenu`, It cann't stop if another's `submenu` has checked I tried `each` function, so jquery condition would be applied only own child element, but it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($("[name='menu[]']:checked").length == 0) {
    alert('Missing menu');
    return false;
  }
  if ($("[name='menu[]']:checked").val() == 2 && $("[name^='submenu']:checked").length == 0) {
    alert('Missing submenu');
    return false;
  }
  if ($("[name='menu[]']:checked").val() == 12 && $("[name^='submenu']:checked").length == 0) {
    alert('Missing submenu');
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('Success');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '#menu', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown('slow');
  } else {
    // these two events
    $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).parent().find('ul').hide('slow');
  }
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

ul li ul li {
  float: none;
}

.col100 {
  width: 100%;
}

ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="2" id="menu">Vehicle
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[2][1]">Bike</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[2][2]">Car</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[2][3]">Cycle</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="12" id="menu">Sport
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[12][1]">Basketball</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[12][2]">Volleyball</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[12][3]">Football</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="col100">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better you implement the check condition which checking the checkbox and make the main checkboxes readonly.

```js
$(function() {
  // Make the main checkboxes readonly.
  $('[name="menu[]"]').click(false);
  $('[name="menu[]"] + ul input').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").prev("input").prop("checked", ($(this).closest("ul").find("input:checked").length > 0));
  });
  $(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("[name='menu[]']:checked").length == 0) {
      alert('Missing menu');
      return false;
    } else {
      alert('Success');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

ul li ul li {
  float: none;
}

.col100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="2" />Vehicle
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[2][1]">Bike</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[2][2]">Car</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[2][3]">Cycle</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="12" />Sport
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[12][1]">Basketball</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[12][2]">Volleyball</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[12][3]">Football</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="col100">
</form>
```

This way, you cannot submit the form without checking the boxes correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Praveen Kumar, your answer seems good alternative, but problem is that, in my project, I set `submenu's` visibility is `hidden` by default, cause there are many other `menu` which may have or haven't submenu. So if one menu has submenu, this `submenu` will be visible only after checking it's `parent` menu, so how to fix it. Please see my updated snippet, I have recently updated. so I am able to clear my problem. Thanks again

Comment: *`Please see my updated snippet, I have recently updated.`* Can't find the update mate...

Comment: Silly me, I'd forget to save edited snippet, please see kindly

Comment: @AnandHmt Ah, super... I was still looking into getting this worked. Sorry mate and thanks for accepting the answer. Meant a lot. `:)` All the best. Have a nice weekend.